# Why is Python string the same if there's no space, but different if there is?

Tags: python, string

I happen to realize the following:

```
a = 'hello'
b = 'hello'
a is b
>> True
```

whereas

```
a = 'hello world'
b = 'hello world'
a is b
>> False
```

If there's no space, the two variables are the same, but if there is they are different.

Why is that?

(I don't need people telling me to use `==` instead of `is`. I know that.)

Comment: Never rely on literals producing the same immutable object. Also, never rely on literals producing *different* immutable objects. It's entirely up to the implementation how to handle literals for immutable types.

Comment: Because the rules for string interning are arcane. It doesn't matter, you should **never rely on this**. The fact that strings like this *are the same* is a fact that should be *surprising*, it is an optimization of the interpreter

Comment: @chepner of course. I'm simply curious as why that's the case.

Comment: Use `==`. `is` is essentially comparing references.

Comment: `a is b` should only be used to see if either `a = b` or `b = a` took place.

Comment: Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks; I snuck "immutable" into my original comment :)

Comment: @MateenUlhaq Interning is expensive, so you want to do it as little as possible, or at least know that the time you spend on the various lookups involved will be worthwhile.

Comment: @chepner Did you mean to reply to someone else? :)

Comment: Sigh. Yup. Sorry about that.